# Why does the Microsoft C library function strrev modify the input string?

Tags: c

When we are passing a string to the strrev function, which is provided by Microsoft, and has the function prototype in string.h. It reverses the string we are passing to it and returns the same address back.

First thing - should it modify the original char array?
Second thing - When it is modifying the same pointer we are passing to it,why should it send it back?!

Comment: I can't find the description of `strrev()` in the [Draft C11 Standard (PDF)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (or in the [Draft C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or in my copy of the C89 Standard).

Comment: Nor does my system provide manpages for `strrev()`. Where exactly did you find this function?

Comment: Final note: `gcc -E /usr/include/string.h | grep strrev` does not return anything either; I've got `libc6-dev` version `2.13-0ubuntu13`.

Comment: `strrev()` is not even in [POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)!

Comment: I am using Microsoft Visual studio 2008 compiler on Windows XP machine,in string.h I found the declaration of the function..

Comment: /***
*string.h - declarations for string manipulation functions
*
*       Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
*
*Purpose:
*       This file contains the function declarations for the string
*       manipulation functions.
*       [ANSI/System V]
*
*       [Public]
*
****/

Comment: @ZoomIn: If you want to write portable code, do not use `strrev()`. Unlike what you say, it is not part of the C standard library. You can write your own function, with the prototype you feel is correct (and call it `mystrrev()` or something else as long as it doesn't start with `str*`).

Comment: @sarnold: It's a widely-available function. For example, you can find one implementation [here](http://www8.cs.umu.se/~isak/snippets/strrev.c) -- it's not part of any official standard as far as I know.

Comment: Please remove all incorrect statements about strrev() being part of any C standard. Also, never trust Microsoft when it comes to standard compliance, they are notoriously poor at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, yes, it should modify the original array. That's its sole purpose.

Second, yes, it should return the pointer to the array. There's nothing else useful for it to return, and sometimes getting the pointer back makes the code more compact, saving the need for a temporary if the parameter passed to `strrev` isn't already stored in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess one of the main reasons is it makes the function run faster. i.e. needs to swap `strlen(s)/2` characters, instead of processing `strlen(s)` characters.

Comment: I'm curious how a string reversal function could do anything except inspect every single byte in a string.

Comment: @sarnold: It could inspect every single byte in a string and also have to write to every single byte in the destination. In place, two characters can be swapped with three operations (XORs). Out of place, four are needed (two reads and two writes). Also, twice as much cache is consumed.

Comment: @David: heh, is that XOR trick really faster on modern hardware than just using a temporary variable?

Comment: @sarnold: I doubt it. The cache consumption difference might matter a bit though. It's hard to imagine anyone reversing enough strings to care.

Comment: @sarnold: use the temporary variable and (optimize code generation and) let the compiler worry about the implementation :)